# How can I access key using value in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dom, dom-events

I'm following a reactJS tutorial from Udemy and I was trying something on my own.

**Project:**
This is a simple project where I can add or remove goals
[image: Screenshot of the project]

What I want to add extra is I want to clear the input text field when clicked on submit(Add goal) button. And I am able to do it but I think there is one problem.

***The Whole Code***

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Button from "../../UI/Button/Button";
import style from "./CourseInput.module.css";

const CourseInput = (props) => {
  const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = useState("");
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(true);

  const goalInputChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredValue(event.target.value);
    if (enteredValue.trim().length > 0) {
      setIsValid(true);
    }
    console.log("=>" + enteredValue);
  };

  const formSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (enteredValue.trim().length === 0) {
      setIsValid(false);
      return;
    }
    props.onAddGoal(enteredValue);
    // empty the inputbar and reset state (enteredValue)
    console.log(event);
    event.target[0].value = ""; // the main 
    setEnteredValue("");       // two lines.
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formSubmitHandler}>
      <div className={`${style["form-control"]} ${!isValid && style.invalid}`}>
        <label>Course Goal</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={goalInputChangeHandler} />
      </div>
      <Button type="submit">Add Goal</Button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default CourseInput;
```

as you can see in above code I'm accessing input field through form events.

[image]

I accessed the input field through index number which I think is hard coded. In future if number of form element increases/decreases there is a chance that index number might change. so what I want to do is access the input value without using index. Is that possible?(I know it is), and how do I do it?

Comment: Where the `enteredValue` does come from?

Comment: Did you mean this index here? `event.target[0].value = "";`

Comment: You can use refs for doing it. Have a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: please show the JSX as well

Comment: entetedValue is a react state. it has value from input field. @Danial

Comment: yes that index @RyanLe

Comment: <form onSubmit={formSubmitHandler}>
      <div className={`${style["form-control"]} ${!isValid && style.invalid}`}>
        <label>Course Goal</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={goalInputChangeHandler} />
      </div>
      <Button type="submit">Add Goal</Button>
    </form>


here we go @Dalvik

Comment: is it a class component or funcitional?@AbbasDahodwala

Comment: You can give your inputs useful attributes like `name` and `id` that you can reference later. You also have, presumably, the form's `onSubmit` event object, just reset the form to clear the fields. Can you share a more comprehensive code example so we can see what all the code is doing? The pictures don't really help explain what your code does.

Comment: i will share my whole code as an answer so its easier to read @DrewReese

Comment: okay i got lot of solutions. thank you very much ya'll, i will try all of them one by one. @everyone

Comment: so i think all are good solutions, how do i mark all of them as correct answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with a form's `onSubmit` action and have the `onSubmit` event then you can reset the form directly.

```
const formSubmitHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (enteredValue.trim().length === 0) {
    setIsValid(false);
    return;
  }
  props.onAddGoal(enteredValue);
  setEnteredValue("");
  event.target.reset(); // <-- calls form's reset action
};
```

```js
const CourseInput = (props) => {
  const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = React.useState("");
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = React.useState(true);

  const goalInputChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredValue(event.target.value);
    if (enteredValue.trim().length > 0) {
      setIsValid(true);
    }
  };

  const formSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!enteredValue.trim().length) {
      setIsValid(false);
      return;
    }
    props.onAddGoal(enteredValue);
    setEnteredValue("");
    event.target.reset();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formSubmitHandler}>
      <div>
        <label>Course Goal</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={goalInputChangeHandler} />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Add Goal</button>
    </form>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <CourseInput onAddGoal={(val) => console.log(val)} />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: could you edit the code as `event.target.reset();` as this is the correct line. cannot access reset through only event.

Comment: First of all **Thank you so much**. This is the simplest one liner code of all the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to add `value={enteredValue}` to input field and set it to empty string after submit the form.
Also if you have any other `input` field, you can try `event.target.reset()`.

So try this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
// import styled from "styled-components";

import Button from "../../UI/Button/Button";
import style from "./CourseInput.module.css";



const CourseInput = (props) => {
  const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = useState("");
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(true);

  const goalInputChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredValue(event.target.value);
    if (enteredValue.trim().length > 0) {
      setIsValid(true);
    }
    console.log("=>" + enteredValue);
  };

  const formSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (enteredValue.trim().length === 0) {
      setIsValid(false);
      return;
    }
    props.onAddGoal(enteredValue);
    // empty the inputbar and reset state (enteredValue)
    setEnteredValue("");
    event.target.reset();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formSubmitHandler}>
      <div className={`${style["form-control"]} ${!isValid && style.invalid}`}>
        <label>Course Goal</label>
        <input type="text" value={enteredValue} onChange={goalInputChangeHandler} />
      </div>
      <Button type="submit">Add Goal</Button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default CourseInput;
```

Comment: Hey this is a great idea too!
instead of resetting whole form as **Drew Reese** said, I will have more control over each elements in form.

Thank you! : )

Comment: @AbbasDahodwalaThanks. I updated answer tobr better answer

Answer (score 1):

You may use `Refs` in order to achieve this:

function MyComponent() {

```
const textInput = React.useRef(null);


const formSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (enteredValue.trim().length === 0) {
      setIsValid(false);
      return;
    }
    props.onAddGoal(enteredValue);
    // empty the inputbar and reset state (enteredValue)
    console.log(event);
    textInput.current.value = "";
  };

  // other code

 return    <input type="text" onChange=        {goalInputChangeHandler} ref={textInput} />
```

}

Comment: More on Refs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly refs work yet, but I'll definitely try it after understanding what refs mean and how they work.
Thanks for the code!

Comment: @AbbasDahodwala in short, refs are react way of doing document.getElementById('')

Comment: Hey @Dalvik, I studied refs, and yes its pretty good approach too, thanks again!